# Getting the Outer-array length in C

Tags: c

To get array length I can (usually) do:

```
sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0])
```

What about if it's a multidimensional array, such as:

```
{"my", "favorite", "things"}
```

How would I get the length `(3)` of that? Basically, the length of the outer-most array.

How is the "end" of the multi-array detected (similar to \0)?

Comment: Post the definition of `array`as used with `{"my", "favorite", "things"}`

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Given `char *array[] = { "my", "favourite", "things" };`, using `sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0])` gives you the answer 3 (and it's the compiler's job to know the size of the array and hence where the end is).  You also get 3 if you use `char array[][16] = { "my", "favourite", "movies" };` and the same expression.  If the array is a function parameter, you don't get the size information.

Comment: in C99 is possible to use `int foo(int bar[static 10])` so that you know the with some sure the minimum size of an array parameter

Comment: I thought that the calculation was done as follows

    arraylen = sizeof(array) / sizeof (type-which-makes-up-array)

eg, `char *` or `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the size of each dimension if you use the quotient of the appropriate, well, dimension:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int array[23][42][7];
  unsigned int size_1 = sizeof array / sizeof array[0];
  unsigned int size_2 = sizeof array[0] / sizeof array[0][0];
  unsigned int size_3 = sizeof array[0][0] / sizeof array[0][0][0];
  unsigned int size_e = sizeof array[0][0][0];

  printf("Size of 1st dimension: %u\n", size_1);
  printf("Size of 2nd dimension: %u\n", size_2);
  printf("Size of 3rd dimension: %u\n", size_3);
  printf("Size of element:       %u\n", size_e);

  return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
Size of 1st dimension: 23
Size of 2nd dimension: 42
Size of 3rd dimension: 7
Size of element:       4
```

There is no "end marker" on arrays in general. You need to track the size if you use dynamically allocated arrays.

The end-of-string marker `\0` does **not** mark the end of the `char` array but the end of the string. The array can be of any size.

---

*Additional notes, not necessarily perfectly worded in the view of the standard's watchmen ;-)*

1. The `sizeof` operator is a (kind of) unary operator for the expression following it. It used to be used with types, so a cast can be given:

   sizeof (int)

   This habit led to the feeling that the parentheses are needed, and that it is a kind of function. **No**, it is not. The result will be calculated by the compiler, and therefore it must be calculatable at compile time.

   If you use it with an object like a variable, you could simply write:

   sizeof variable
2. If you have a `char` array at the (second) most inner dimension you would probably liek to call `strlen()` on each of them. This might apply also to `char*` as element type.

Answer (score 0):

The array you've showed is a pointers array:

```
 char *array = {"my", "favorite", "things"}
```

you can use the same syntax of

```
sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])
```

to get the number of items at array, which are the number of pointers at array.